# Why wont the timer be invaliated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am working on a project that requires the user to tap the screen to stop and object. I need to invalidate ShakeTimer once the screen is tapped but whenever I run the app it doesnt stop the timer. I have tested the touches began part by ordering it to hide an image when I tap and that has worked but I just cant invalidate the timer. AAAAh. Why. code is below for you.

```
#import "Game.h"

@interface Game ()

@end


@implementation Game

-(IBAction)Play:(id)sender{

   ShakeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(Shake) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

     Play.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [ShakeTimer invalidate];
}

-(void)Shake{
    CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [shake setDuration:1];
    [shake setRepeatCount:INFINITY];
    [shake setAutoreverses:YES];
    [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                         CGPointMake(Piece.center.x - 5,Piece.center.y)]];
    [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                       CGPointMake(Piece.center.x + 300, Piece.center.y)]];
    [Piece.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    Leave.hidden = YES;}

-(void)GameOver{
    Leave.hidden = NO;    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not about the timer stops or not, it's about the animation.

your timer is only invoked one time (as `repeats:NO` below):

```
ShakeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(Shake) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

but the animation seems repeats infinitely:

```
[shake setRepeatCount:INFINITY];
```

#### Solution:

If you want to stop the animation once user touches view, you need to remove the animation:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [Piece.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"position"];
  ...
}
```

---

#### Edit:

If you want to start the animation again when user touch the view next time:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (self.layer animationForKey:@"position") {
    [ShakeTimer invalidate];
    [Piece.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"position"];
  } else {
    [self Play:nil];
    // or just 
    // ShakeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(Shake) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  }
  ...
}
```

Actually, i think you even don't need the timer to handle it:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (self.layer animationForKey:@"position") {
    [Piece.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"position"];
  } else {
    [self Shake];
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oooh so obvious. Thank you! ill try that. Thanks. But I have a follow up question. Later on could I start the animation again.

Comment: @Jaa4226 if u need to start the animation again, u need to reset the timer to let it starts again.

Comment: And I would do that by saying [self Shaketimer] right?

Comment: I have run into another problem. I  cant get the animation to start when I tap play because when I do that I remove the timer. Is there any way to make it so the button tap is not classified as a screen tap.

Comment: @Jaa4226 u can use `CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]; if (CGRectContainsPoint(aSubview.frame, touchPoint)) {...}` to get a touch on specific subview;